# C basics. How to create a loop for 2 different login Pin numbers

Tags: c

Here are my source code. I want to create an ATM program that can login with 3 different PIN numbers. Actually I'm new in C basics. So, I don't know much about what's wrong with my code or anything.

In this problem, I tried to create a loop for 2 different login pin numbers. But 1 of them are ignored. Meaning that, I can only enter the pin using pin_A while the pin_B is invalid ([PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh191.png)).
I also tried to keep both of the pin code (pin_A,pin_B) in a same place like,

```
while(pin_A!=121212||pin_B!=131313)
{
    printf("\nEnter your PIN:");
    scanf("%d",&pin_A,&pin_B);

    if(pin_A!=121212||pin_B!=131313)

        printf("\nInvalid PIN\nPlease enter a valid PIN number\n");
}
```

but it seems the program still can't read them.

I already tried to search the internet about this. But much of them are in C++ code. I don't understand anything that come with C++. I really appreciate anyone that would like to help me.

Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>

int balance_A=1500,balance_B=4700,balance_C=2300;
int pin_A,pin_B,pin_C;
int anotherTransaction_A=1,anotherTransaction_B=1,anotherTransaction_C=1;

int main()
{
    int choice;

    printf("Choose your language:\n");
    printf("1.English\n");
    printf("2.Bahasa Malaysia\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:

            printf("\n***********WELCOME TO SIMPLE AUTOMATED TELLER MACHINE**********\n");

            /*---------------FIRST DATA---------------*/

            while(pin_A!=121212)
            {

                printf("\nEnter your PIN:");
                scanf("%d",&pin_A);

                if(pin_A!=121212)

                printf("\nInvalid PIN\nPlease enter a valid PIN number\n");
            }


            while(anotherTransaction_A==1)
            {
                int option;

                printf("\nWhat do you want huh:\n\n");
                printf("1.Check your balance\n");
                printf("2.Withdrawal\n\n");
                scanf("%d",&option);

                if(option==1)
                {
                    printf("\nYour balance is: RM%d\n",balance_A);
                }
                else if(option==2)
                {
                    int amountWithdraw;
                    printf("How much money do you want to withdraw: RM");
                    scanf("%d",&amountWithdraw);

                    if(amountWithdraw<=balance_A&&amountWithdraw%50==0)
                    {
                        balance_A=balance_A-amountWithdraw;
                        printf("\nYour balance is RM%d\n",balance_A);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if(amountWithdraw>balance_A)
                        {
                            printf("Insufficent money\n");                      
                        }               
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid transaction\n");            
                }

                anotherTransaction_A=0;

                while(anotherTransaction_A!=1&&anotherTransaction_A!=2)
                {
                    printf("\nDo you want to do another transaction?\n");
                    printf("1.Yes\n2.No\n");
                    scanf("%d",&anotherTransaction_A);

                    if(anotherTransaction_A==2)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }



            /*---------------SECOND DATA---------------*/

            while(pin_B!=131313)       //SECOND PIN
            {

                printf("\nEnter your PIN:");
                scanf("%d",&pin_B);

                if(pin_B!=131313)

                    printf("\nInvalid PIN\nPlease enter a valid PIN number\n");
            }

            while(anotherTransaction_B==1)
            {
                int option;

                printf("\nWhat do you want huh:\n\n");
                printf("1.Check your balance\n");
                printf("2.Withdrawal\n\n");
                scanf("%d",&option);

                if(option==1)
                {
                    printf("\nYour balance is: RM%d\n",balance_B);
                }
                else if(option==2)
                {
                    int amountWithdraw;
                    printf("\n\nHow much money do you want to withdraw: RM");
                    scanf("%d",&amountWithdraw);

                    if(amountWithdraw<=balance_B&&amountWithdraw%50==0)
                    {
                        balance_B=balance_B-amountWithdraw;
                        printf("Your balance is RM%d\n",balance_B);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if(amountWithdraw>balance_B)
                        {
                            printf("Insufficent money\n");                      
                        }               
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Invalid transaction\n");            
                }

                anotherTransaction_B=0;

                while(anotherTransaction_B!=1&&anotherTransaction_B!=2)
                {
                    printf("\nDo you want to do another transaction?\n");
                    printf("1.Yes\n2.No\n");
                    scanf("%d",&anotherTransaction_B);

                    if(anotherTransaction_B==2)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }


            break;

        case 2:
            printf("/nSELAMAT DATANG KE ATM!/n");
                break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps reading the manual page for `scanf` will help you identify the problem in this line `scanf("%d",&pin_A,&pin_B);`

Comment: Important: Code is written for humans to read. Thus, your code should be readable! First of all, use a proper and clear indentation. Then - and if you follow this your path will become a a lot easier - try to break your problem into subproblems, and solve each of them separately. Also: Use functions where ever meaningfully possible.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do. You want the user to have to enter 2 PINS? Thats like having one big PIN. Do you mean there are 2 valid PINs and the user can enter either. Do you mean there are 2 PINs and you have to enter a different one depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

The loop should look like this:

```
while (pin_A != 121212 && pin_B != 131313)
{

    printf("\nEnter your PIN:");
    scanf("%d %d", &pin_A, &pin_B); 

    if (pin_A != 121212 || pin_B != 131313)

        printf("\nInvalid PIN\nPlease enter a valid PIN number\n");
}
```

you missed an %d in the scanf... now it should work...

twice %d = get two numbers

Comment: BTW, it should be `if (pin_A != 121212 && pin_B != 131313)`

Comment: Please check the return value from `scanf` (it must be `2` here). If you are writing software for a secure mechanism you must check everything you can possibly check. Also, reset the PIN entry values first for extra security. A colleague wrote software for a PIN-open safe: I opened the safe just by pressing `Enter`! Because the previous entry was still in the variable, and the invalid entry left that intact.

Comment: Now fix the `if (scanf("%d %d", &pin_A, &pin_B) != 2) { throw error }`

Comment: @Weather Vane (BTW, nice crack you [PoT](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102798/))  &   David C. Rankin: Password code should avoid any function, like `scanf()`, that may have internal buffers that are not scrubbed after usage.  Even `fgetc()` is not so great.  Password code needs to scrub its own buffers too, before returning.